# how can I kill a Firebase transaction?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have transaction in a Firebase database working for the last 5 hours. That transaction  is trying to remove a large node, but it is using 100% of the database, so I have to kill that transaction in order to make the database available again.

[Database load](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2omiU.png)

Anyone knows how can I kill that transaction?

Comment: Where is it running?

Comment: @DougStevenson: running on Firebase hosting (Google Cloud). Actually, my problem is that, using it as SaaS it's imposible to reset the database or whatever

Comment: Code doesn't run inside Firebase Hosting.  Are you saying it's running on a web browser from JavaScript served by Firebase Hosting?

Comment: @DougStevenson: my backend is running on AppEngine (java, std environment), but it has nothing to do with the issue. The app is running fine, but the database is not able to process any request because its load is above 100%. The transaction I need to kill was made from python (pyrebase library), but that process ended because of a timeout.

Comment: If the transaction is running in App Engine, can't you just kill the GAE instance? If it's already killed, then I don't see how it could be causing any load.

Comment: At this point, if you don't know what to do next, you should contact Firebase support directly, as I don't think SO is going to be of any help to you. https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/

Comment: @DougStevenson: the problematic transaction was the python one, was a node.remove(), and that python raised an error a few minutes after its start, so that process is not alive any more. I was trying to remove a large node, and I think the real time database is still trying to do so. My situation right now is that the backend application (the one in appengine) is not able to reach the db because that db is busy doing sth for more than 9 hours now. Thks for your interest!

Answer (score 1):

Just for others facing a similar issue... after reaching to Firebase support, they have confirmed that:

- Once a delete request has started, there's nothing we can do for stopping it and the only thing you can do is wait for the operation to finish. Mine is already almost 10 hours and still working on it!
- Deleting large nodes should be done with the firebase-tools cli, command 'firebase database:remove'. This command would delete the nodes of your database by dividing them into chunks and thus, preventing your database instance from locking-up.